# Do I need to install SQL Server 2008 SP1 on the management studio express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

Basic Question -

I have installed [SQL Server Express 2008 with integrated SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=01af61e6-2f63-4291-bcad-fd500f6027ff). This is the database engine alone.

I realise now that I also need the express studio in order to perform a few tasks. I have installed it, however I know that it was the original installer from before SP1 was released.

I have tried it and it appears to work fine but should I install SP1 / could something unforeseen happen in the future?

Some background! -

I wrote out the question and just realised that people probably don't care, so I just summed it up above!

After reading many different sites and guides, the install order for Visual Studio 2008 really confused me.

I really wanted to install SQL Server Express 2008 with advanced services, however on my other machine I had so many problems with it not being detected with Visual Studio, I just wanted an easy life!

I found the download from Microsoft that had SQL Server Express 2008 with SP1 integrated, however it was only the basic engine without any addons. (At the end of the day, as much as I wouldn't mind reporting services, I doubt I will need to use it any time soon).

I installed this, and after applying the hotfix (for x64 sql) my Visual studio can detect and use it no problem.

Now, I want to use Management Studio Express to write a few SQL scripts. The installer is obviously the original one. It seems to work fine, but I cannot find out any information - do I need to install SP1 for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install it, if its found something it can update - it will, if not... it won't....

Comment: Thank you, two answers pretty much with the same advise. I am going to run the update and then flip a coin to see which of you gets marked as answers - but both being marked up! You can be tails!

Comment: Went from 10.0.1600.22 to 10.1.2531.0 after update. Thank you, and tails won!

Comment: Thanks you... there are some software on the net that make these checks for you on all installed software and recommend updates.
I usually don't use them- as I prefer to wait a while to see if the update brings more trouble than good and then install....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the wonder of Windows Installer (and I don't mean "I wonder why it's doing that?"--I mean like "This is wonderful!") it is unlikely that you have caused any big issues by running the older version afterwards.

So, yeah, you can probably just install the [SQL 2008 Express Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=www.microsoft.com%2Fweb%2Fwebpi%2F2.0%2FWebProductList.xml%3Bwww.microsoft.com%2Fweb%2Fwebpi%2F2.0%2FWebProductList.xml&appid=134%3B135) with no worries. If you want to be sure, afterwards just run the [SP1 installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en) and it will make sure everything's up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you, two answers pretty much with the same advise. I am going to run the update and then flip a coin to see which of you gets marked as answers - but both being marked up! You can be heads!

Comment: Went from 10.0.1600.22 to 10.1.2531.0 after update. Thank you, but tails won! sorry :(

Comment: No worries 'bout the points... but I'm glad you have it working!

Answer (score 1):

I always make sure to apply patches to client tools as well as server services.  There is no reason to take the chance that your client tools have fallen behind in servicing.